# ios Listing all files in a directory phonegap 3.4.0

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3, fileapi

Hello Im developing an ios application using phonegap but Im having hard times accessing files as follow:

receivedEvent: function(id) {
    function errorHandler(error)
    {
        alert(error.code);
    }
    function toArray(list) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(list || [], 0);
    }
    window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT,1024*1024,go, errorHandler);

```
function go(fs) {


fs.root.getDirectory("/", {},

                     function(dirEntry)
                     {

            var dirReader = dirEntry.createReader();



                     var entries = [];


   var readEntries = function() {
    dirReader.readEntries (
             function(results) {
        if (!results.length) {

                           }
                           else {
                    entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
                           for(var i=0;i < results.length;i++)
                           {
            alert(results[i].fullPath); 
    console.log(results[i].toURL());


                           }
                                readEntries();
                           }
                           }, errorHandler);
                     };
                     readEntries(); // Start reading dirs.
              }
                     , errorHandler);
}
```

}
}

when I enter fs.root.getDirectory("/"...
the result of  alert(results[i].fullPath); is:
/Documents/, /www/, /imgs/(???? that is so strange as imgs is inside www in my workspace why is it appearing in the root folder ), /cocloud/
if i replace "/" with "/www/" or anything els I dont get any results?! therefore I get list of directories or files in my project ;(
also if I put any folder or file in the Staging directory which I understand is the root or resource directory it dose not  appear 
even if I use "/" for search query example: fs.root.getDirectory("/"...etc ??  can some one help pleas How can I list all files inside some folder in ios knowing that I added those files manualy to the project www/imgs folder. Cane some one help me pleas?!

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade plugin to 1.2.0
2. Use window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL

Example: window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'/www/img', function(dirEntry){...}, errorHandler);

Hope that helps. See also [Phonegap file plugin- copy file from app package to persistent storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067878/phonegap-file-plugin-copy-file-from-app-package-to-persistent-storage/24346143#24346143)