# Phonegap file plugin- copy file from app package to persistent storage

Tags: ios, file, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins

Issue:
Using Phonegap on iOS I want to copy a image from the application package example

```
http://localhost/img/test.png
```

to the local persistent storage.

I'm ok getting the persistent storage via *window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail)*. But how do I get the folder of the www root? Per file plugin docs I assume I somehow need to use cordova.file.applicationDirectory. Unfortunately the doc doesn't specify where/how to do that. I've tried some ways but no luck so far.

Any ideas?

Environment:
-Phonegap 3.4
- org.apache.cordova.file plugin 1.1.0 (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md)
- iOS Simulator 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out now.

1) Upgrade plugin to 1.2.0
2) Use window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL

Example:
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'/www/img', function(dirEntry){...}, errorHandler);

As phonegap files are always below www don't forget that folder.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your org.apache.cordova.file to 1.2.0

Comment: Hi, two things. Cordova 3.5 was tested with version 1.1 [link](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/05/23/cordova-350.html). So can't be that wrong. Secondly ... your answer doesn't answer how to use it :-)